# Can design patent be renewed?

Tags: patentability, patent-applications, design-patent

The lifetime of design patent is 14 years (for designs which were filed before May 13, 2015) / 15 years (for designs which were filed on or after May 13, 2015) from the date of grant.

Answer (score 1):

The lifetime of design patent is 14 years (for designs which were filed before May 13, 2015) / 15 years (for designs which were filed on or after May 13, 2015) from the date of grant.
It doesn’t have any maintenance fee during their lifetime and expires once the design rights term completed. unfortunately, design patents cannot be renewed. Once a design patent expires due to the expiration of the 15-year patent term, a design patent holder cannot to renew the patent.

If you have a design and patent on that expired design patent, try to come up with a new design that’s similar, yet different enough to convince the patent office to grant you a design patent.